# Does conditional Indexing work with IndexedEmbedded?

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing, hibernate-search

I couldn't find anything on the internet, so I have to ask here.

[How] Can I use conditional Indexing with embedded entities? I know that an interceptor works on the root level of an @Indexed Entity, but not if I can somehow apply an interceptor to a non-root entity (which is not annotated with @Indexed) in my indexing structure.

The documentation of EntityIndexingInterceptor.onCollectionUpdate(...) makes me hope that this can be achieved.

"A CollectionUpdate event is fired on collections included in an indexed entity, for example when using IndexedEmbedded This event is triggered on each indexed domain instance T contained in such a collection; this is generally similar to a onUpdate(Object) event."

Comment: or do I have to do that in @Transient annotated methods (and check that myself?)

Comment: I think it could be done with a ClassBridge as well, am I right? The @Transient approach seems to be really slow, because I have to eagerly fetch Collection-Type properties.

Answer (score 0):

The interceptor needs to be specified on an indexed entity. It is only available as an attribute to the @Indexed annotation. If this annotated entity used @IndexedEmbedded, you will get a callback in the interceptor if the embedded collection changes.

What exactly is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works, check out here for example: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/api/org/hibernate/search/indexes/interceptor/EntityIndexingInterceptor.html#onCollectionUpdate(T)

Basically you get a call to onCollectionUpdate, so if you want to filter something there is the place to do it. I guess you were concerned about that.